# Proper way to handle error in django

Tags: django

Hi everyone
I just realized that on deployment, debug = False, doing something like this:

```
    try:
        fb_friends_raw = retrieve_and_store_fb_friends(request.facebook.uid, request.facebook.access_token)
    except Exception, e: 
        messages.error( request, 'Cannot retrieve your friends, do it later.' + str(e))
        return HttpResponseServerError('Cannot retrieve your friends, do it later.' + str(e))
```

will bring you to just a plain html file with the error as the main body rather than 500.html. I don't think that 404 is suitable because it is a server error rather than a page not found.

Obviously when the user encounters this problem, I want to render the base template which has a logout button where the user can start from scratch. I 
currently have that in 500.html and 404.html.

What is the proper way to deal with errors on deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `HttpServerResponse` is simply an `HttpResponse`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseServerError

500.html is loaded when a view **raises an exception**.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

If you want to render a specific template for this exception, you can simply return a regular response but modify the `status_code` to 500.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code

For example:

```
response = direct_to_template(request, "mytemplate.html", {})
response.status_code = 500
return response
```

Comment: Ok thanks. According to the docs, """Django will e-mail the users listed in the ADMINS setting whenever your code raises an unhandled exception and results in an internal server error (HTTP status code 500). """ So if I return a response with status code 500, I don't think that will trigger the email. I will go with the 500 server error view then.

Comment: Incidentally, is it possible to pass in args to 500 view?

Comment: also, if you need to pass context variables to your error pages (like MEDIA_URL), you need to do it explicitely. see https://gist.github.com/809780

Comment: just call raise Exception('this is an exception') to trigger the 500.html page + automatic debug email

Comment: Note, `direct_to_template` has long since been removed from Django, so this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @Cerin noted, but it was also asked 5 years ago - perhaps not worthy of a downvote.